# react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default is not defined on a simple setState

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-jsonschema-forms

I am using a library called `react-jsonschema-form-conditionals`. I am using its function called `applyRules` like its documentation says to use it:

`let FormWithConditionals = applyRules(schema, uiSchema, rules, Engine)(Form)`

However, when I put a functional component in `uiSchema` like this:

```
const uiSchema = {
    name: {
      "ui:widget": (props) => <div></div>,
    },
  }
```

I have a `react-dom` error that is caused by a `setState` inside the library : `react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined`. The library tries to make a setState with the `uiSchema` inside the new state but fails to do so.

I am using react and react-dom 16.8.6.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I'm getting the same error

Comment: I didn't find a solution so I stopped using react-jsonschema-form-conditionals :/